# form doesn't appear - UnboundLocalError at / DJANGO FORM

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-errors, django-uploads

my form doesn't appear at my website and its error now. this is my error message :

> UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'form' referenced before
> assignment Request Method:    GET Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
> Django Version:   3.0.14 Exception Type:  UnboundLocalError Exception
> Value:     local variable 'form' referenced before assignment Exception
> Location: F:\KULIAH\SEMESTER8\SKRIPSI\MusicLockApp\MusicLockApp\views.py
> in homepage, line 20 Python Executable:   C:\Users\Capoo\python.exe
> Python Version:   3.10.2 Python Path:
> ['F:\KULIAH\SEMESTER8\SKRIPSI\MusicLockApp',
> 'C:\Users\Capoo\python310.zip',  'C:\Users\Capoo\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\Capoo\lib',  'C:\Users\Capoo',
> 'C:\Users\Capoo\lib\site-packages'] Server time:  Thu, 19 May 2022
> 06:33:52 +0000

[image: error]

here's my views.py :

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Audio_store(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['record'])
            return render(request, "homepage.html", {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request, "homepage.html", {'form': form})
    return render(request, "homepage.html")
```

html :

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <button type="submit" class="dsnupload">
                                <i class="large material-icons" style="font-size: 50pt; margin-top: 10px;">audiotrack</i>
                                <p style="font-weight: bold; color: white;">Insert file audio (mp3)</p>
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{form}}
                            </button>
                          </form>
```

form.py :

```
from django import forms

class Audio_store(forms.Form):
    record=forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'style': 'width: 300px;', 'class': 'form-control'}))
```

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
     url(r'^decode/$', views.decode),
     path("", views.homepage, name="upload")
 ]

if settings.DEBUG: #add this
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

i want my form appear instanly, please help me

Comment: also add `handle_uploaded_file()` function to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just like this and the form will appear instanly.

```
   def homepage(request):
        form_class = Audio_store
        form = form_class(request.POST or None)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = Audio_store(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['record'])
                return render(request, "homepage.html", {'form': form})
        return render(request, "homepage.html", {'form': form})
```

Comment: Needs to treat the case when the request is not a POST

Comment: it's work on me. when not post, the form still appear. just look the last code @JohnDoe

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Audio_store(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['record'])
            return render(request, "homepage.html", {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request, "homepage.html", {'form': Audio_store()})
    return render(request, "homepage.html")
```

example
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#the-view

Answer (score 0):

When you click on URL, a GET request is executed. As per your code when request goes in to else part where request suppose to show an empty form but you have not defined form class object and pass this object as a context in return statement that's why you are getting this error.

Try this code:

```
def homepage(request):
    form = Audio_store()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Audio_store(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['record'])
            form.save()
            return render(request, "homepage.html", {'form': form})
    return render(request, "homepage.html", {'form': form})
```

Hopefully It will work for you.

Comment: form.save() just for modals. i'm not using it